# How to join multiple related models using select_related or prefetch_related in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have 5 related models that I want to show in my template. For every `Collection` I want to show all `Product` that belong to corresponding collection (`ProductCollection`). The informations I need for every product are: a name (`ProductAlias`) and the default image (`ProductImage`).
The raw query should be like:

```
SELECT c.name, pa.name, pi.image
FROM Collection c JOIN ProductCollection pc ON c.collection_id = pc.collection_id
JOIN Product p ON pc.product_id = p.product_id
JOIN ProductAlias pa on p.product_id = pa.product_id
JOIN ProductImage pi on p.product_id = pi.product_id
WHERE pi.default = 'True' and pa.market_id = 1
```

`models.py`:

```
class Collection(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()

class Product(models.Model):
  video = models.URLField()

class ProductCollection(models.Model):
  collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ProductAlias(models.Model):
  product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  market = models.ForeignKey(Market, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  name = models.CharField()

class ProductImage(models.Model):
  product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  image = models.ImageField()
  default = models.BooleanField()
```

I seperate name of the product into another model because 1 product has many names depending on the region they're marketed at. A product also has many images. But I only need the global name (`market_id = 1`) and the default image (`default = True`) for every `Product`.

My current attempt on `views.py` with function-based view (without applying the filter yet because I already got ValueError during template rendering):

```
def collection_view(request):
  # tried to chain the prefetch_related on multiple models but failed.  
  collections = Collection.objects.prefetch_related('productcollection__product__id', 'productalias_set', 'productimage_set').all()
  context = { 'collection_list': collections }
  return render(request, 'product_visualizers/collection.html', context)
```

My current attempt on template `collection.html`:

```
{% for collection in collection_list %}
  <h3>{{ collection.name }}</h3>

  {% for pair in collection.productcollection_set.all %}  # what should I loop here to show the product name and product image?
    <p>{{ pair.product.product_id }}</p>  # tried to display the product_id but failed.
    <p>{{ productalias_name }}</p>  # product name.
    <img src="{{ image.url }}">  # product image.
  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue isn't caused by using prefetch/select related. These are only for reducing duplicate queries. Your `pair.product.product_id` should be `pair.product.id`

With how you've setup your models, you have many ProductAliases to one Product and many ProductImages to one Product. You'll need to loop over both of their sets to get the image and name fields.

```
{% for alias in pair.product.productalias_set.all %}
    {{ alias.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

```
{% for product_image in pair.product.productimage_set.all %}
    {{ product_image.image }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi Airith. Thank you for answering my question. I think my function context in `views.py` is also wrong. What should I change my `collections` variable into? Is it just `collections = Collection.objects.all()` ?

Comment: Try `collections = Collection.objects.prefetch_related('productcollection_set__product__productalias_set', 'productcollection_set__product__productimage_set').all()`